# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging

I want to write some react code,but it doesn't work.
I use chrome.but I get

warning-->
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/programe/code/Vscode/ReactDemo/HelloWorld/test.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
babel.min.js:24

error-->
GET file:///D:/programe/code/Vscode/ReactDemo/HelloWorld/test.js net::ERR_FAILED

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>hello,everyone!</h1>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: Yeah that's because you are trying to load a JS file directly from your file system (file:///D:/). Browsers will never allow that for security reasons. You need a web server to serve your files (apache, Node.js, etc.)